# How to list all files that an Android app is currently reading or writing?

Tags: files, data-monitoring, resource-monitoring

I want to list all the files that an Android app is currently reading or writing, something like what Windows' Disk Activity in Resource Monitor does:

> [image: IMG:]

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you have root access? `toybox lsof` command should help.

Comment: @Firelord Android L (5.1.1) or earlier: `toolbox lsof` (`toybox` was only introduced in 6, or Android M).